# Remote CPP debugging in a Docker Container

Tags: vscode-remote

I want to get remote C++ debugging working on my laptop with Windows 10 Professional, the latest version of Visaul Studio Code Insiders edition, and the latest version of Docker Desktop.  I'm following the guide "Developing inside a Container" (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) and trying to get the sample project working under "Quick start: Try a dev container" with the repo https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-try-cpp.

After I start debugging, I only get options for restart and stop. There are no options for stepping over or into code, the debugger view doesn't display anything, and the break points don't seem to do anything.

Any idea of how to fix or troubleshoot this?  I can open a terminal window, browse the container contents, and the source code from the repo is accessible from inside the container. I can run containers in Docker separate from Code Insiders, and local folders mount and are accessible from within containers with no apparent problem.

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide that will help troubleshoot this. I appreciate your help.

-Ed

Comment: I tried this from another computer and it worked. I'm not sure what the difference is between the two systems, but I'll try to troubleshoot it and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled everything, reinstalled it, including extensions, and everything worked this time...